# PHP Fatal error: Class 'Controllercommon' not found in C:\Inetpub\Low Vision - Philippines\vqmod\vqcache\vq2-system_engine_loader.php on line 28

Tags: php, opencart, vqmod

Please Help me on this

i have cleaned vqcache folder and checked but it's not working.
any solution on this.

this issue only for product category page. other pagers are working good.

**Error**
http://ph.lowvision.co.nz/index.php?route=product/category&path=59_60

**server specification**
windows server
PHP Version (please check the link) http://ph.lowvision.co.nz/version.php

Comment: Please add the relevant code snippet and the error inline and not as a link, as it will age away and is not of any value for the community afterwards ...

Comment: Also add the opencart version

Comment: opencart Version 2.1.0.1

Comment: Show the xml file.If possible thea share vQcache file `category.php`

Comment: which xml file you want to see?  there no file call category in vQcache folder

Answer (score 1):

Hi can you please check the following. In your  root folder of opencart setup go to system/storage/modification/ folder in that if there is folder named "system"  then please delete this folder for now and check your site will run. i have the same problem with opencart same verison.  one more thing do not clear cache of modification on admin side. if you clear it. the folder named "system" will again generate in system/storage/modification/ so again you have the same error.  i hope this will work for you.